# Outlook-Viewing External Invitation Acceptance When Sent Via Resource

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, calendar, office365

I have a user sending a meeting invitation through Outlook (Office365) via resources. They are sending it this way because they want the people invited to remain anonymous. Sending an invitation this way will not allow you to see whether or not invitees have accepted the meeting invitation.

I have 2 questions.

1. Is there a better way to send an invitation in Outlook that would allow the people that accepted to remain anonymous and let you view whether or not they have accepted?
2. Is there a way to enable resources to allow you to see who has accepted the invitation?

I have tried following this support article to no avail:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2331322

The Web App does not have the option to "Automatically process requests and responses from external senders."

Any advice would be great,

Thank you.